# laravel first0rNew Integrity Constraint Violation

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, integrity

I'm using Laravel Eloquent's firstOrNew() function to retrieve a DB record based on 3 criteria:

```
$summary = $this->firstOrNew(array(
    'date' => $date,
    'product_id' => $product_id,
    'store_id' => $store_id,
     ));
```

I also have a unique composite key of those 3 fields.

Even though the record exists, the function doesn't retrieve it, so when I update an attribute and run `$summary->save()` I get the wonderful

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry >'2015-01-02-6-23' for key 'date_product_store_unique'

Any ideas?

Laravel version is 4.2.

Comment: Are you sure the data  store in the variables that are passed is what you are expecting?

Comment: I've debugged the input, in fact, the firstOrNew() function creates a new object with that exact data. I believe the issue has to do with the unique key not being the primary key, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Laravel 4 doesn't support composite keys http://laravel.io/forum/09-25-2014-models-for-tables-with-multiple-columns-for-primary-key maybe Laravel 5 does... I dont know

Answer (score 2):

Laravel 4.2 doesnt support composite keys!